# Progress Calendar in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, calendar, progress

I'm building a progress calendar feature in my app. There is a progress bar in my app, if the user reaches 100% at the current day, I want to show them a checkmark in the calendar so they can see in which days they completed their goal.
What would be the way to build it?
I guess I can have a variable for each day of the month and make it true if the user reaches 100% for that day, but that seems like a really bad solution.

Here is my calendar usage.

```
CalendarView(interval: year) { date in
  if calendar.component(.day, from: date) == calendarCurrent.component(.day, from: currentDate) {
    ZStack {
      Text("30")
        .hidden()
        .padding(8)
        .overlay(
          RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous)
            .stroke(Color(red: 50/255, green: 104/255, blue: 144/255), style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2))
        )
        .padding(.vertical, 4)
        .overlay(
          Text(String(self.calendar.component(.day, from: date))).bold()
        )
        .foregroundColor(.white)
    }
  } else {
    ZStack {
      Text("30")
        .hidden()
        .padding(8)
        .background(Color(red: 50/255, green: 104/255, blue: 144/255))
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
        .padding(.vertical, 4)
        .overlay(
          Text(String(self.calendar.component(.day, from: date))).bold()
        )
        .foregroundColor(.white)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your question is too broad and lacks information. What kind of model do you have and how do you persist your data?

Comment: In my App I only track the daily progress of the user so I store the progress value into UserDefaults and reset it every day.
I don't have data from previous days, that's why I though the easiest way would be to have a boolen to be true when the user hits 100% on the progress bar.

Comment: But how will you be able to keep track of previous days then?

Comment: My idea was to create a dictionary with a days of the month and a bool value. That way I can save it for example jan. 17: true because the user reached 100%. Would this be possible to persist in userDefaults?

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem by saving the data into a dictionary and update its value daily.